# Convert AWS APIGateway's Model to JSON in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using Amazon's APIGateway service client side. When you make a request the data returned is stored in a Model data type that the schema is set up beforehand. the calls look like this:

```
MyModel myModel = client.settingsPost();
String volume = myModel.getVolume();
```

the schema for this simple object would look like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "MyModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties" : {
      "volume" : { "type" : "string" }
  }
}
```

I would like to convert the Model returned directly to JSON instead of having to go manually reconstruct a new JSONObject from each value of this Model. The Models seem to be very simple and I cant even iterate through them. But I wonder if there is a way to convert them using the GSON library somehow?

EDIT: I am using the APIGateway SDK generated to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myModel);
```

Using Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myModel);
```

Comment: Yup this is exactly what I needed! I tested both with positive results! Thanks :) Then to convert to a org.Json object I just did new JSONObject(jsonInString);